# Dual band hotspot (DBS)

Tags: root-access, wifi-hotspot

Phone has [snapdragon 765g processor](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/mobile/snapdragon/smartphones/snapdragon-7-series-mobile-platforms/snapdragon-765g-5g-mobile-platform), which natively support dual band hotspot (2.4g and 5ghz), plus Android 12 has support for [DBS](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-ap-ap-concurrency), but the settings screen doesn't show any option to enable DBS.

How do I enable DBS?

Comment: What phone do you use? Android in general may have DBS hotspot support but manufacturer often don't use original AOSP version instead use a modified version and forget to include certain features of new Android versions.

Comment: I use one plus device, is there any adb means to activate it, even if it's rooted how do I activate it?

Comment: @Chemist your phone support dual band in client mode. But not in a server (wifi ap mode) your best bet is to buy a device that ships with android 12 or 13 and has a wifi driver that support dual band in wifi ap mode

Comment: Didn’t know that, Thanks